# MessagePack deserialize exception FormatterNotRegisteredException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization, msgpack

I have a unity project where i need to be able to deserialize really fast. I tried MessagePack. I followed the tutorial but when the deserialization is triggered i receive this error:

**FormatterNotRegisteredException: DeserializedObject is not registered in resolver**

This is my class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using MessagePack;

[MessagePackObject]
public class DeserializedObject
{
   [Key(0)]
   public SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, ushort[,]>> features;

}
```

i call this from other class like this:

z-represents the bytes.

```
DeserializedObject ds = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<DeserializedObject>(z);
```

So i wonder how can i register my class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i did was to generate resolver and formatter  using this:

```
1. mpc.exe -i "..\src\Sandbox.Shared.csproj" -o "MessagePackGenerated.cs" -m
2. restart unity +  vscode
3.
    var resolver = MessagePack.Resolvers.CompositeResolver.Create(
                    NameOfGeneratedNamespace.Resolvers.NameOfResolver.Instance);
    var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(resolver);

    DeserializedObject ds = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<DeserializedObject>(z,options);
```